# A building imported from Blender is missing parts

Tags: unity, blender, fbx

I want to make a scene that a player can log into using my django server and walk around.

So, I created a simple building inside Blender that resembles my school's building. (And yes, the building from the SIMS would look 1000 times better because all I have been using is cubes and loop cuts and extrudes)

[image: Screenshot of model in Blender]

I exported this building from Blender as an FBX format. And then when I drag and drop it into the Unity, some of the parts are gone.

[image: Screenshot of model in Unity]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to create a simple model that demonstrates this issue? What's the shortest sequence of cube/loop cut/extrude operations we can do to get a model that imports wrong, based on your tests?

Comment: Ah, I don't understand your question well, but since I don't know much about 3D modelling and since I'm just a beginner, (just followed a donut tutorial from blenderguru and an another easy character tutorial because I just want to include this in my project due this month), I just get into edit mode of a cube and start adding shapes and if I want to make a window or a door, I just create multiple loop cuts and delete the face. @DMGregory

Comment: Try starting a new Blender file. Add a cube. Make one of your modifications. Then import it into Unity to check how it looks. If it still matches, then we haven't found the problem yet. Go back to Blender, and modify the cube a bit more, keeping track of the changes you make, and re-importing into Unity regularly to check the result. Once you get a version that looks different in Unity than in Blender, you've identified a specific sequence of steps that we can follow to reproduce the issue on our own computers. With that in hand, it's much easier to troubleshoot and test potential solutions.

Comment: Also, something to test: If you move the Unity camera inside one of those "missing" sections, and turn it to look outward, do you see the wall from the inside? It's possible your faces got reversed, so they only show up from inside-out instead of outside-in.

Comment: I think the problem exists in the larger objects, because I have made three chairs and they all are imported fine like this https://imgur.com/a/wBwKTMJ

Comment: That's fine, but we can't tell you what the problem is until you give us the steps to take to reproduce it. We could spend all day in Blender randomly loop cutting and extruding and not produce the specific outcome you created. So we really need you to do the legwork of identifying a specific set of instructions that we can follow to demonstrate this problem. Pay particular attention to polygons with more than 4 sides — it looks like those are the ones disappearing in your example, so focusing on that may help you find a simple test case to share.

Comment: You are absolutely right about that inside-out, sir. It's harder to move as I scroll my middle button, so I couldn't check it easily and I didn't focus on that because I thought there were no such things. But when I check from the inside, I could see those missing parts, however, the visible ones did go missing. Is there a way to make it as it is all the time? The closest experience I have with buildings is The SIMs video game, so I think in there has three options on how you wanna look your building, and I am hoping Unity provides something like that.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this Q&A from the Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15802) or [this procedure for correcting your face normals](https://blenderartists.org/t/my-mesh-got-turned-inside-out/323189)

Comment: Thank you for your help, sir! Although some parts are still missing, following those have improved the building by much.

Comment: Great! Want to edit your question to show the remaining problems, and the steps we need to take to reproduce them so we can test ideas for solutions?

Comment: Suree!! I have two imports, one is calculated inside, and one is calculated outside. I have decided to go with calculated inside one, because I want to create a scene with a character that can go around the building. However, either way, some parts are still missing. But I think I can just fill them with planes from Unity.